# How to correct high volume drop off using a slider

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, audio, slider

This is my first time using a volume slider and it's the one provided from the 3D shooter tutorial on the Unity3D website. The slider works but after about the middle of the slider, the volume is already barely perceptible. It feels like it's dropping off too quickly for a slider of that size compared to sliders I'm used to, and I'm guessing there is some trig function I could use to make the dropoff smoother, but I'm not familiar enough with them yet. Does anyone know of a good way to correct this? Thanks! Here's the code I've got for it

Edit: I found this VolumeHandler script as well. I'll put it after the first one

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class MixLevels : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioMixer masterMixer;

    public void SetSfxLvl(float sfxLvl)
    {
        masterMixer.SetFloat("sfxVol", sfxLvl);
    }

    public void SetMusicLvl (float musicLvl)
    {
        masterMixer.SetFloat ("musicVol", musicLvl);
    }
}

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class VolumeHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        if(GameObject.Find("EffectsSlider"))
        GameObject.Find("EffectsSlider").GetComponent<Slider>().onValueChanged.AddListener(SetVolume);
    }

    void SetVolume(float volume)
    {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = volume;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if(GameObject.Find("EffectsSlider"))
        GameObject.Find("EffectsSlider").GetComponent<Slider>().onValueChanged.RemoveListener(SetVolume);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could u post "Inspector" screenshot of the sliders?

Comment: You don't need a trig function. I think you can just pass the slider's input value through a simple logarithmic function. The input domain should start at 1.  You may have to play with the log's base. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/osibvmz8ga

Comment: To get an audible linearity to volume, the function is a square. It would not surprise me if Unity cubed it. They almost never do things the way all other software and interfaces do things.

Answer (score -1):

If after about the middle of the slider, the volume is already barely perceptible, this means that the value in the middle should be the maximum value on the slider.

Select the Slider and change the *Max Value* to the value in the middle of the slider when the volume becomes barely perceptible. You can also do this from code with the  `Slider.maxValue` property. As for smoothness, make sure that "Whole Numbers" is not enabled on the slider. If it is enabled then the slider value would be `int` instead of `float` which can cause issues.